# Are Partition Boundaries IDs (in sys.partition_range_values eg.) guaranteed to be ordered by partition range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-partitioning

Suppose you have a Partition Function, and you are dynamically adding and removing Range Boundaries to that Function, using `ALTER PARTITION SPLIT RANGE` and `ALTER PARTITION MERGE RANGE`.

You can interrogate `sys.partition_range_values` to establish what the current range boundaries are.

It appears that no matter what you create, split and merge the ranges in, that `sys.partition_range_values` table will always show that the boundary_ids (and equivalently the partition ids, in other `sys` tables) are in ascending order of the boundary values.

**Is that actually guaranteed?**

**Can I be certain that boundary_id 1 will always be the left-most boundary of the Partition Function?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I be certain that boundary_id 1 will always be the left-most
> boundary of the Partition Function?

Yes. This is specifically called out in the [sys.partition_range_values documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partition-range-values-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> ID (1-based ordinal) of the boundary value tuple, with left-most
> boundary starting at an ID of 1.

My interpretation of "left-most boundary starting at an ID of 1" is that boundary values are ordered. The [`CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION` doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-partition-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) also mentions boundary value ordering:

> If the values are not in order, the Database Engine sorts them,
> creates the function, and returns a warning that the values are not
> provided in order. The Database Engine returns an error if n includes
> any duplicate values

Comment: Perfect answer! Clear, to the point, and cited :D